# SnakeYaml parsing Yaml files to java Objects

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I am trying to parse below yaml file content to java object but getting excepion.

this is yaml file content

beforeSuiteActions:

- !include \commonSteps\getConfig.yaml
- !include \commonSteps\adminLogin.yaml
- !include \commonSteps\login.yaml
- !include \commonSteps\getDeviceDomain.yaml
- !include \commonSteps\getLinearChannels.yaml
- !include \commonSteps\getAssetList.yaml

can anyone suggest why it is giving exception

Comment: Please show your current attempt and the exception that you get

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: In particular, you need to show what you have implemented to process those `!include` tags.